# Is there any way to read two different names from same column?

Tags: mysql, database

I have table and in the images column I am saving the names of the images needed for that row data, I want to know if there is any way to read multiple image name which are in the same column(and row) and fetch corresponding image from the folder.

I can read one image name and fetch that image from the folder, but not more than one.

Do I have to create multiple column to achieve this?

Comment: Provide code and table structure to?

Comment: See normalisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even of you could, its not a good design to store multiple  image names on the same column(not just for images, but any type of data in general),  research about "normal forms"(or normalization) in database design, the best approach would be to store them on another table with a 1 to many relationship(the images table would have a foreign key to the original row),this way you can easily fetch image by image with a simple join ,and use the current code "for one image" you already have

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL 2016 have [JSON storage support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jocapc/2015/05/16/json-support-in-sql-server-2016/). You could store the names in JSON in a single column and return the result as JSON. Something like:

```
SELECT a.ImageNames FROM table1 a FOR JSON
```

Then you could load the JSON into an object with a list property.

Some variation of that. It's difficult to tell because we don't know what language or framework you're using other than MS SQL. But if you want to store multiple values in a single column/row, JSON would be a good way to do it.

You could also just use a simple CSV value.